# Upgrade Magento 1.3.2.2 to 1.6.2.0

Tags: magento

I want to upgrade an online shop from Magento 1.3.2.2 to 1.6.2.0.

Can someone tell me what is the easiest way to do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

easiest way is to search before asking :) as this has been covered here few times

- backup your site
- generate all indexes, disable caches
- disable all 3rd party extensions and local overwrites
- disable all theme customizations and set to use default theme
- upgrade version by version and backup each step (generate indexes and clear cache in between)
- when on final version enable custom extensions one by one and debug

Comment: How can I do this exactly? "upgrade version by version and backup each step (generate indexes and clear cache in between)"

Comment: download every version and upgrade by deleting everything that's in magento folder and replace with new package + add local.xml again every time . if you don't know other ways for this or automate this. Backup is just backup from filesystem and database

Comment: Anton is correct, I would advise going to 1.4.0, then 1.4.1, 1.4.2, etc. This process will take quite a long time coming from 1.3.2, and there is a very good chance none of your extensions will work anymore. You are working with a very old version of Magento, so unless you don't have many custom extensions, theming updates or modifications, I would recommend a completely clean install of 1.6.1 then working with that (will most likely be 'cleaner' and less headaches than trying to catch up on the most recent version). You generally don't want to fall behind more than 1 major release.